# How to convert price by format

Tags: c#, javascript, e-commerce, format

I have encountered with a problem with pricing.
I need to format price input to be of the type XXXX.YY
the problem is, the input price can be of shape XXX,YY in europe or XX,XXX.YY if talking about big numbers.

Is there a JS or C# lib that helps there?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for **American / British** format:

```
Double.Parse("123,456.78", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

for **German** format:

```
Double.Parse("123.456,78", new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

Hint: If you are storing / reading data from file/Database etc. it is generally advisable to make use of CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Comment: If you are storing it in a database, send the date as a DateTime value in a parameter.

Comment: @Cylon Cat: This is about doubles, not dates

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Decimal.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z.aspx) rather than Double.Parse when dealing with currency values.  (The Decimal type reduces the possibility of rounding errors etc.)

To answer your question about differing cultural currency formatting, from MDSN:

> Parameter s is parsed using the
>   formatting information in a
>   NumberFormatInfo initialized for the
>   current system culture. For more
>   information, see CurrentInfo. To parse
>   a string using the formatting
>   information of some other culture, use
>   the Decimal.Parse(String,
>   IFormatProvider) or
>   Decimal.Parse(String, NumberStyles,
>   IFormatProvider) method.

In case you are not aware, the .NET framework automatically takes the "current system culture" from the current regional settings of the operating system.  In Windows this can be viewed/changed by the computer user in the "Regional Settings" or similar.

Comment: my first comment was about the fact, that Decimal.Parse does round instead of truncate

Answer (score 0):

```
Double.Parse("123,456.78")
```

will work in C#

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be.aspx

Then ToString it to the format you want:

```
String.Format("£{0:##.##}", number);
```